# ImportError cannot import name FunctionSet

Tags: python, python-2.7, chainer

I have installed chainer but I still get this error pls help fix it!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hoda/Downloads/vae-1-master/source/vae_mnist.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chainer import FunctionSet,Variable
ImportError: cannot import name FunctionSet
```

this is part of the code

```
from chainer import FunctionSet,Variable
import chainer.functions as F
import numpy
from vae_model import VAE_bernoulli,VAE_gaussian
```

Comment: How did you install the chainer? Also, are you using python virtualenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/upgrade.html

> Some obsolete classes and functions are removed
>   chainer.FunctionSet (Use [Chain](http://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/core/link.html#chainer.Chain) or [ChainList](http://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/core/link.html#chainer.ChainList) instead)